# Moving SSRS Subscriptions with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, reporting-services

I am trying to move SSRS Subscriptions between servers. The report has already been moved to the new server.  I've seen multiple blog posts which seem to indicate this is possible.  HOwever, they rely on an the powershell command

`set-RsSubscription -path`

and on my powershell, that parameter doesn't exist.
the overall script looks something like this:
`Get-RsSubscription -ReportServerUri "http://testserver/reportserver" -Credential $credential -path "/Reports/Report 1" | 
Set-RsSubscription -ReportServerUri -path "/Reports/Report 1"` `

the set-rssubscription -path isn't accepted.
Note that I am on SQL Server 2016 on both servers.   Reporting Services tools are at 0.0.4.6.

Comment: Your path seems to be incorrect. Refer to http://redglue.eu/does-that-copy-subscriptions-too-now-it-does-new-powershell-ssrs-commands/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there has been a change to Set-RsSubscription:

"There was a major breaking release on v0.0.4.0 which means that my scripts on this blog post may not work. In fact, the Set-RsSubscription is one of them. If you use the Get-Help Set-RsSubscription you can see that -Path parameter no longer exists. This command, as it is today just work to set some subscription properties. The command you are looking for is the Copy-RSSubscription. Please take a look at the examples provided with the help. I leave here just one:

`Get-RsSubscription -ReportServerUri 'http://localhost/ReportServer_sql14' -RsItem '/path/to/my/oldReport' | Copy-RsSubscription -ReportServerUri 'http://remote-machine:8080/reportserver_sql16' -RsItem '/path/to/newReport'`

http://redglue.eu/does-that-copy-subscriptions-too-now-it-does-new-powershell-ssrs-commands/

Also, currently you may run into issues with Copy-RSSubscription

https://github.com/Microsoft/ReportingServicesTools/issues/172